# Is it possible to detect wheter a MethodInfo object refers to a sub or a function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I'd like to distinguish between these two cases, for example in this code:

```
For Each method As Reflection.MethodInfo In Type.GetType("WindowsApplication2.clsTest").GetMethods()
    Select Case method.Name
        Case "ToString", "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print(method.GetType().ToString)
    End Select
Next
```

Or, even better, is it possible to iterate only over subs or functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably the `ReturnType` property will tell you what type it returns and, while I haven't tested, I'd expect that that property would be `Nothing` for a `Sub`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The `ReturnType` of a `Sub` is `Void`, not `Nothing` because it's internally used by the .NET framework itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MethodInfo` class has a [`ReturnType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype) property and the return type of a `Sub` is [`Void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.void), so you can do something like this:

```
For Each method As Reflection.MethodInfo In Type.
                    GetType("WindowsApplication2.clsTest").GetMethods().
                        Where(Function(m) m.ReturnType IsNot GetType(Void))

    Select Case method.Name
        Case "ToString", "Equals", "GetHashCode", "GetType"
        Case Else
            Debug.Print(method.Name)
    End Select
Next
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much.